# How to float multiple paragraphs next to an image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So... I'm a coding newbie and I'm already struggling for multiple days with the following problem.

I want to have multiple lines of text next to a picture. However, trying to achieve this with the float-parametric fails, because the text that should be next to the image consists of multiple paragraphs.

To illustrate:

I want my text and "^" to look like this:
[Desired situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOL9V.png)

But with my code (see below) I only manage to achieve this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC3H6.png)

So I don't seem to be able to get my text - which should be three different lines of text - next to the image.

This is what I got up until now:

CSS:

```
.grey{
   background-color: #f9f9f9;
   height: 100%;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #d9d9d9;
   border-left: 0;
   border-right: 0;
   clear: both;
}

.titel{
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight: normal; 
   font-family: "Roboto Slab", Georgia, serif;
   color: #19232d;
   float: left;
}

.datum{
   font-size: 14px;
   padding: 11px 0 0 0;
   font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
   color: #d9d9d9;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   float:left;
}

.link{
   font: 21px;
   padding: 11px 0 0 0;
   font-weight: normal; 
   font-family: "Roboto Slab", Georgia, serif;
   color: #19232d;
   float: right;
   text-align: right;
}

.naamspeler{
   font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
   color: #d9d9d9;
   float: right;
}

.afbeeldingspeler{
   float: right;
   padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

.huidigeranking{
   font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
   color: black;
   float: right;
   font-size: 2em;
}

.rankingup{
   color: green;
   float: right;
   font-size: 2em;
}

.rankingdown{
   color: red;
   float: right;
   font-size: 2em;
}
```

HTML (it's Wordpress, therefore the [columns]) :

```
<div class="titel">Op de ladder</div> 
<div class="datum">   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;5 december 2015</div> 
<div class="link"><a href="/opdeladder">Meer rankings ></a></div>

<div class="grey">

[columns]

[column size="1/3"]
<span class="afbeeldingspeler"> <img src="http://tennisplaza.be/beta/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/David-Goffin.jpg" width=93px /></span>
<span class="rankingup"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-up fa-4x"></i></span>
<span class="huidigeranking">16</span>
<span class="naamspeler">+4</span>
<span class="naamspeler">David GOFFIN</span>
[/column]

[column size="1/3"]<span class="afbeeldingspeler"> <img src="http://tennisplaza.be/beta/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Yanina-Wickmayer.jpg" width=93px /></span>
<span class="rankingup"><i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-4x"></i></span>
<span class="huidigeranking">44</span>
<span class="naamspeler">+4</span>
<span class="naamspeler">Yanina WICKMAYER</span>
[/column]

[column size="1/3"]<span class="afbeeldingspeler"> <img src="http://tennisplaza.be/beta/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Niels-Desein.jpg" width=93px /></span>
<span class="rankingdown"><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-4x"></i></span>
<span class="huidigeranking">250</span>
<span class="naamspeler">-20</span>
<span class="naamspeler">Niels DESEIN</span>
[/column]

[/columns]

</div>
```

Furthermore, on mobile devices, this doesn't seem to work at all. There, none of the CSS seems to be working (no colours, no different fonts sizes, no floating)...

Does anyone has any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: The WP shortcode's only purpose is the making of the three columns. 

`.column.one-third { width: 33.333333333333336%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to wrap the column contents in a div or span? If you can do that, it'll allow you to use text-alignment: right and to float the spans to the right. Right now it doesn't appear that you have any span or div binding the spans together in one block.

Comment: It is possible, but it does not appear to change anything. The result stays the same.
I both tried removing the float out of the underlying elements (such as .huidigeranking and .naamspele), and keeping them, but the result stays the same.